# Model binding on radio button(s) returns null for that property (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, model-binding

So I have four radio buttons that are bound to one of my model's properties all with different values. However, when the form submits, that property is returning null (while everything else returns correctly). Code:

```
<div id="RadioButtonGroup">
    <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="A"  type="radio" name="optradio" >Option One
    </label>
    <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="B"  type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Two
    </label>
    <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="C"  type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Three
    </label>
     <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="D"  type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Four
    </label>
</div>
```

I select one, submit the form, and `Object.PropertyOne` returns null. But if I manually set `Object.PropertyOne` in my ViewModel, it displays correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not specify a `name` for your radio buttons manually.  If you remove `name="optradio"` you will see that the tag helper will emit a name.  The Model Binder will not correctly process your property if you specify your own name.

You can see this in action by adding a second property `PropertyTwo` and looking at the source code and debugging the controller.  You will find that `PropertyTwo` has a name of `Object_PropertyTwo` for each radio button, and that it will bind correctly (whereas `Object.PropertyOne` still fails to bind):

**Model**

```
 public class MyObject
   {
      public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
      public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyModel
   {
      public MyObject Object { get; set; }
   }
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Foo()
  {
     return View(new MyModel() { Object = new MyObject() });
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Foo(MyModel model)
  {
     return View();
  }
```

**View**

```
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Test Page";
}

@model MyModel

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Foo" method="post">
   <div id="RadioButtonGroup">
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="A" type="radio" name="optradio" >Option One
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="B" type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Two
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="C" type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Three
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" value="D" type="radio" name="optradio" >Option Four
      </label>
   </div>
   <div id="RadioButtonGroup">
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyTwo" value="A" type="radio">Option One
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyTwo" value="B" type="radio">Option Two
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyTwo" value="C" type="radio">Option Three
      </label>
      <label asp-for="Object.PropertyOne" class="radio-inline">
         <input asp-for="Object.PropertyTwo" value="D" type="radio">Option Four
      </label>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Wow thank you immensely for the detailed and well-explained answer! I was able to remove the custom name and it worked flawlessly just like you said. These small things are sometimes so hard to catch and easy to miss, so thanks again. I would have spent so much wasted time trying to figure it out.

Comment: The name attribute exist to group all radio buttons into the group having the same value for the name attribute. If I must not set that name explicitly knowing which radion buttons belong in which group, how does asp.net core know that?

Comment: @Elizabeth,   The property name passed to the asp-for attribute is used for the values of both the id and name attributes. 
However, you can override this behavior by supplying your own unique id value for each element.
Since the asp-for attribute dictates the group name, the different info set for the value attributes will go into one string variable.